# extract information from mysql query in NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have the following function that i use to extract information from my DataBase

```
exports.getSinglePrice=  function(dbConnection, uid, tableVariable ,table, callback){
    var myQuery = 'SELECT ' + tableVariable + ' FROM ' + table + ' WHERE uid= ' + uid;
    var query = dbConnection.query(myQuery, function (err, row, result) {       
        //console.log(query.sql);
        if (err) {
            console.log("getSinglePrice error");
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }

        var price= row[0].tableVariable;

        console.log("\n\nprice is : " , price);
        callback(price);
        return;
    });
};
```

i have 3 tableVariable, that i need to extract. the problem i have is with the following line:

```
        var price= row[0].tableVariable;
```

i cant use tableVariable, cause i dont get any information back, but have to give the exact name of the variable, for example in my case:

```
    var price= row[0].MoneyForPrivacy;
```

or

```
    var price= row[0].MoneyForLocation;
```

or

```
    var price= row[0].MoneyForEnvironment;
```

any ideas how i can generalize my function.

Comment: If tableVariable is string You need to use this way `var price= row[0].[tableVariable]`

Comment: @Molda, i get the following error 

var price= row[0].[tableVariable];
                                  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Comment: Sorry typo. No dot between brackets row[0][table...]

Comment: @Molda, you are the man!! thank you

Answer (score 0):

the answer is to do the following:

```
price= row[0][tableVariable];
```

when tableVariable is a String.